# Toyota Yaris xp9 2006 Clock is inactive

Tags: toyota, electronics, yaris

I have Toyota Yaris xp9 Model 2006. When I start car. I do not see any more clock. It is totally off. Could you please inform me the reason why this fault happened and how I can repair it?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the fuse?

Comment: Have you checked any of the things mentioned? Posting a repeat question is not good: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/80874/10976

Answer (score 2):

Possible reasons, apart from the fuse mentioned above that come to mind are:

- Failed wiring
- Failed clock
- Failed display (i.e. the clock is working but you cannot see it any longer)

Keep checking things until you find the source of the problem.